# Easiest way to create stand alone application from python script

Tags: python, exe

I am a bit of a noob in this department, so I was wondering what is the easiest way (i.e. least amount of time and effort) to create a stand alone application from a python script.

Comment: http://www.py2exe.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question `[exe]`, I assume it is Windows-specific. Take a look at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/):

> py2exe is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do so, in Windows, is to use [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), see [this tutorial](http://www.logix4u.net/component/content/article/27-tutorials/44-how-to-create-windows-executable-exe-from-python-script).